# Downloading csv file using Play Framework?

Tags: scala, file, csv, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to add to my app a simple button that on click will call an Action that will create a csv file from two lists I have and download it to the user computer.

This is my Action:

```
def createAndDownloadFile = Action {

    val file = new File("newFile.csv")

    val writer = CSVWriter.open(file)

    writer.writeAll(List(listOfHeaders, listOfValues))

    writer.close()

    Ok.sendFile(file, inline = false, _ => file.getName)
  }
```

but this is now working for me, the file is not getting downloaded from the browser...

im expecting to see the file get downloaded by the browser, i thought `Ok.sendFile` should do the trick..

thanks!

Comment: If you send your request as Ajax, it might not work as expected, try opening in a separate window, when doing your request.

Comment: @mavarazy how do i do that?

Comment: A target in link should be blank

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Enumerators](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Enumerators) and streams for that. It should work like this:

```
val enum   = Enumerator.fromFile(...)
val source = akka.stream.scaladsl.Source.fromPublisher(play.api.libs.streams.Streams.enumeratorToPublisher(enum))
Result(
  header = ResponseHeader(OK, Map(CONTENT_DISPOSITION → "attachment; filename=whatever.csv.gz")),
  body = HttpEntity.Streamed(source.via(Compression.gzip), None, None)
)
```

This will actually pipe the download through gzip. Just remove the `.via(Compression.gzip)` part if that is not needed.